# Redirect to the selected tab

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap in Symfony 1 application. I've a tabbed navigation but I want to get redirected to the same tab I was after perform a add action. See this [image](http://www.dropmocks.com/mBtbPZ) as you may see I in **Emisores** tab, I want after perform a Add action (is "Crear Nuevo") I got redirected to the same tab. For redirection I use this:

```
$this->redirect('admin/index');
```

Is that possible? How?

Comment: you could add a `#` to the link and then retrieve it with JS. Then depending on the `#` you do specific actions, like opening that `tab`

Comment: @Spokey already try that (the part of add a `#` to the URL) but Symfony response is `route not exists`

Comment: You can't redirect to a tab. You can only redirect to a URL. You can store information the URL or session that can be used to activate a tab. How do you activate tabs on your page?

Comment: @antony since I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) then I can use `$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show');` using the tab name, in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011598/modules-views-and-actions-inside-tabs?noredirect=1#comment24595168_17011598) you tell me something about store in sessions active tab but then what? since the activation is made by Javascript and using jQuery how I deal with this?

Comment: Easy. Just store the id of the active tab in your session before you do a redirect `$this->getUser()->setFlash('activeTab', 'profile');`. Then in your javascript do this `$('#myTab a[href="#<?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('activeTab', 'default_value'); ?>"].tab('show');`

Comment: @antony hmm in which actions I must track session? I've all this methods in `actions.class.php`: `executeIndex(), executeNew(), executeCreate(), executeEdit(), executeUpdate(), executeDelete(), processForm()` and also in `components.class.php` I've `executeIndex()` so where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller

```
// \apps\myApp\modules\profile\actions\actions.class.php
public function executeUpdate()
{
    // Handle form submit and update

    $this->getUser()->setFlash('activeTab', 'profile');
    $this->redirect('admin/index');
}
```

Now in your template, you can tell what was the last activated tab because you stored the name of it in the flash object before you did the redirect. So retrieve the flash value to determine which tab to activate in your template like this:

```
// \apps\myApp\modules\admin\templates\indexSuccess.php
<script>
     <?php 
     // Would be better if assigned this in your controller and passed it to the template
     $activeTab = $sf_user->getFlash('activeTab', 'default_tab_id');
     ?>
     $('#myTab a[href="#<?php echo $activeTab ?>"]').tab('show');
</script>
```

Comment: thanks I get it now, it don't works at all because of jQuery or some mistake with Twitter Bootstrap but this is another topic, thanks for your help